# Best way to share variables in node processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipc, node-modules, shared-memory

Suppose I have 2 two processes like these:

## file1.js

```js
let variable1 = "variable1"
```

## file2.js

```js
let variable2 = "variable2"
```

that have both been spawned using

```
node file1.js
node file2.js
```

Is there a way to let them communicate? For example can I get `variable1`'s value from `file2.js`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want file1.js and file2.js to be in the same node.js project and process?  Then, you could share data with import and export very easily.  Without that, you'll have to use one of the many intra-process communication tools that are available.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a master node js and `fork` 2 child node js process than you can communicate data between `parent and child`.

**Basic example:**

```
const fork = require('child_process').fork;

const program = path.resolve('child.js');
const parameters = [];
const options = {
  stdio: [ 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'ipc' ]
};

const child = fork(program, parameters, options);
child.on('message', message => {
  console.log('message from child:', message);
  child.send('Hi');
});
```

**More:**
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options